# Adding JDesktopPane to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

Is it possible to add `JDesktopPane` and `JInternalFrame` to a `JPanel` if so how could I do it. I tried adding it but it couldn't work.

Comment: As was stated in your last [question on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874242/adding-jdesktoppane-to-jframe-using-gridbaglayout), unless you provide an [example that demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your problem, there's very little people to can do.  The short answer is, yes.

Comment: While I agree to what MadProgrammer said, a wild guess: Did you forget to call `internalFrame.setVisible(true)` ? In any case, this should be a good starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Answer (score 4):

> *"Is it possible to add JDesktopPane and JInternalFrame to a JPanel"*

Sure you can

```
desktop = createDesktopPane();
JInternalFrame iFrame = createInternalFrame();
desktop.add(iFrame);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("DesktopPane"));
panel.add(desktop);
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class JDesktopPaneDemo1 {
    private static final String URL_ONE = "http://www.hdbackgroundspoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/16/345t34.jpeg";
    private static final String URL_TWO = "http://www.hdbackgroundspoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/hh.jpeg";
    private Image image;
    private JDesktopPane desktop;

    public JDesktopPaneDemo1() {
        desktop = createDesktopPane();
        JInternalFrame iFrame = createInternalFrame();
        desktop.add(iFrame);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("DesktopPane"));
        panel.add(desktop);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Desktop Background");
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setSize(500, 350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        iFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JDesktopPane createDesktopPane() {

        JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane() {
            private Image image;
            {
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(new URL(URL_ONE));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            }
        };
        return pane;
    }

    private JInternalFrame createInternalFrame() {
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        return frame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf : UIManager
                .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName())) {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                        | IllegalAccessException
                        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JDesktopPaneDemo1();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `URL_TWO` for?  It does not seem to be used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson `image = ImageIO.read(new URL(URL_ONE));` I was making a couple different examples (for a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22866831/2587435)) and I wanted to make it easier for myself to switch images